Vuetify flex wrap order
I'm working with a flex container that has four items. The third item has a variable width based on dynamic content. When the container runs out of space, I want the third item to wrap to a new line, rather than the last item.
I've tried different flexbox configurations, but the last item always wraps first, which isn't the behavior I'm looking for. How can I force the third item to wrap when there's no more room?
Here's an example image of the desired behavior.
Thanks in advance for your help!


Vuetify has flex order classes that can change the order of elements. You need to figure though when that order change should happen. Not sure if it can be done with vuetify's breakpoints somehow. Maybe adding css tag will help get more attention? Are you using v-rows with v-cols or something different?
